# Why does the C++ STL use RBtree to implement "std::map"?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Nowadays I am looking python source code, and I found both python and C# use hash to implement `Dictionary`.

The time complexity of hash is `O(1)` and `RBtree` is `O(lgn)`, so can anybody tell me the reason why the `C++ STL` uses `RBtree` to implement `std::map`?

Comment: You shouldn't be blinded by asymptotics. BSTs and hash tables are very different data structures, and you can only really know which one is better for your problem by measuring. Since hash tables have more difficult requirements for the key type and are more complex, the tree-based *ordered* map was a more natural first choice for an associative container, but as of C++11, we have both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it has a separate container for hash tables: `std::unordered_map<>`. Note also that .NET has `SortedDictionary<>` in addition to `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: You may want to mention the additional requirements to `std::map` (being sorted that is), which make it different from `Dictionary` and equal to `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks, so in RBtree it is possible to pick out all items that are in a certain range, but in hash table we can't do that, right?

Comment: "The time complexity of hash is O(1)" - in the best case. The worst case is still O(n). rb tree uses balance techniques to achieve log(n) for all cases. And, plus, the difference in the order of course.

Comment: @lai yes, you can use lower_bound in std::map to get sorted range.

Comment: @innochenti: Correct of course, but in practice I doubt you'll ever really hit that O(n) case.

Comment: @GManNickG: but with a red-black tree, you're *guaranteed* you'll never have lookup, insert or delete with `O(n)` performance.  In some applications, having a good upper bound is better than having a good average running time or a good lower bound.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Like I said, in practice you're never going to hit that O(n) worst case. I can say you're guaranteed to never have O(n) hash table implementations, but instead of looking at asymptotic behavior for my justification I'll just point out that you won't be using such a small table when you actually apply the data structure to your code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in "The Standard C++ Library, A Tutorial and Reference", available online here: http://cs-people.bu.edu/jingbinw/program/The%20C++STL-T&R.pdf.

Short quote explaining:

> In general, the whole standard (language and library) is the result of a lot of discussions and
>   influence from hundreds of people all over the world. For example, the Japanese came up with
>   important support for internationalization. Of course, mistakes were made, minds were changed,
>   and people had different opinions. Then, in 1994, when people thought the standard was close to
>   being finished, the STL was incorporated, which changed the whole library radically. However, to
>   get finished, the thinking about major extensions was eventually stopped, regardless of how
>   useful the extension would be. Thus, hash tables are not part of the standard, although they
>   should be a part of the STL as a common data structure.

Obviously since that time c++ 11 has come out, and since the name `map` was already taken, and `hash_map` is a name that was already widely used via common extension libraries (e.g.__gnu_cxx::hash_map), the name `unordered_map` was chosen for hash maps.